# File is properly included however class doesn't exist

Tags: php, class

I am trying to extend a class from an included file however when the file is properly included. I get a fatal error telling me the class doesn't exist.

This is the file where I want the class to be extended. Global.php (line 2) is an autoload function.

```
namespace epsilon{
    include("global.php");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

    class epsilon extends Database{
          static $name = "Me";
    }
```

Global.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $namespace = str_replace("\\","/", __NAMESPACE__);
    $class = str_replace("\\","/",$class);
    $path = __DIR__."/classes/".(empty($namespace)?"":$namespace."/")."{$class}.class.php";
    #var_dump($path);
    require_once($path);
});
```

Lastly, the this file is the class. Which I want to extend the epsilon class.

```
class Database{

}
```

> Fatal error: Class 'epsilon\Database' not found

Comment: Can you show what `$path` outputs?

Comment: Does it work if you call it specifically with `extends \epsilon\Database` ?

Answer (score 1):

You must add \ before Database class, because it's not under epsilon namespace.

```
class epsilon extends \Database{
      static $name = "Me";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Answer is probably wrong as had not originally realised Qwentalis was trying to extend a class in the same namespace rather than a global namespace class.
>   I will update this answer with a more correct version with some feedback on comments by Qwentalis (or delete this answer)

Class epsilon is extending `epsilon\Database` because it's defined in the epsilon namespace, so simply put `class epsilon extends \Database` to force it to extend the *global* namespace class called Database.

You can define this behaviour by preceeding the calls with a blackslash, examples, what is in angle brackets is assumed by PHP :

1) Your current call:

```
class epsilon extends <current namespace\>Database
```

2) your intended call (please read my note above):

```
class epsilon extends <global namespace>\Database
```